# Can I use Sieve method without using Array and Boolean?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, sieve-of-eratosthenes

We were given an assignment in our computer programming 4 class to create a program that will list all the prime numbers below 600 using sieve method but the problem is our professor doesn't allow us to use concepts that she still doesn't teach us and few of those concepts are Boolean and Array. My question is, is it possible to create this program without using Array and Boolean?

Comment: In theory, yes, but you should probably ask your professor for clarification on what, exactly, you're allowed to use.

Comment: Are you sure you are required to use the sieve method? The prime numbers can be found naively, without using the sieve.

Comment: Have you learned Sets yet?